# Post comment to a modern site page using REST api

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

Posting to the below endpoint for comments on a site page throws an error.
Endpoint:

```
/_api/web/Lists('<sitepagesguid>')/GetItemById(305)/Comments
```

Response:

```
The expression \"web/Lists('cd1dae9b-e3a7-45fc-a610-8069e3dd081d')/GetItemById(305)/Comments\" is not valid.
```

Site page comments are not stored in a list and don't follow the same schema so how do I post comments via REST endpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below REST API format to fetch the comments from the sitepage,

```
/_api/web/Lists('<sitepagesguid>')/items(305)/Comments
```

To add a comment to the page, use the below URL, with post method

```
/_api/web/Lists('<sitepagesguid>')/items(305)/Comments
```

Body: `{"__metadata":{"type":"Microsoft.SharePoint.Comments.comment"},"text":"my  comment"}`

Method: POST

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I had tried and got the error for some reason - now it works. Can any other properties such as the comment author be passed to Sharepoint or is that still not possible?

Comment: Is there a way to post comment on behalf of another user? I'd like to migrate comments from one site to the other, and maintain original authors of the comments...